# Return drawing in initial state (ilnumerics)

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I use ilnumerics library by math's graph drawing. After using of "zoom in", "zoom out" features, there is no possibility to return graph in initial state (only not elegant way, in my opinion, to redraw it). I used methods like "PerformAutoScale", also I tried to refresh Panel and Scene objects, but I didn't achieve the necessary result. Also, I was searching "scene" object properties that may be charge of scaling, but didn't find it too. Are there any way to decide it?

Comment: Asking a question and not showing your code will make it difficult for SO members to help you.  I _highly_ suggest you update your post and show the code that you are having difficulties with in addition to explaining what you have tried.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please try to improve! A code example - as Sly suggested - might make your problem more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I start to learn english not so long ago. I consider your notes in next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
scene.First<ILPlotCube>().Reset();
```

Alternatively, you may double click on the plot. This does also reset the scene to the initial state.

Comment: "double click on the plot" - This is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!